# How to build a model where variance depends on covariate?

Tags: r, regression, linear-model

I have what I believe is a very simple problem for anyone used to modelling with unequal variances (which I am unfortunately not). I have a dependent variable "totrich" which I want to model as a function of a covariate "years" and a two-level factor "spont". Essentially I am just interested in whether spont is a significant predictor of totrich, but I need to control for years. The problem is that the variance in totrich is clearly negatively correlated with years (the younger the children (years) the more variable their behaviour (totrich)).

I am trying to use `gls()` but I am over my head and I'm am not exactly sure how to specify that the variance in totrich depends on years. I have tried this:

```
mod2=gls(totrich~years+spont,data=dfm,weight=varPower(form=~years))
summary(mod2)
```

I think this makes a model that says the variance in totrich is related to a power of years, which seems to make sense, but there are other ways to do it and I'm not sure which is right. I would very much appreciate if someone could put me out of my misery and tell me how I should be setting the weights!

Here is my data

```
years   totrich spont
4.202739726 7   N
4.18630137  6   Y
4.128767123 6   N
4.150684932 6   N
4.150684932 6   N
3.717808219 7   N
4.15890411  5   N
4.24109589  3   Y
4.178082192 3   N
3.997260274 4   Y
4.22739726  3   Y
4.030136986 3   N
4.15890411  2   Y
4.216438356 6   Y
4.98630137  5   Y
6.654794521 6   N
6.4         3   Y
7.112328767 2   Y
6.673972603 4   Y
6.712328767 4   Y
6.693150685 5   Y
6.695890411 4   Y
5.679452055 4   N
6.660273973 3   Y
6.912328767 3   Y
6.687671233 3   Y
6.679452055 3   N
6.542465753 1   Y
6.597260274 3   Y
6.695890411 3   N
6.624657534 4   N
6.624657534 4   N
6.490410959 4   Y
6.663013699 2   Y
6.643835616 6   N
6.605479452 6   Y
8.161643836 3   Y
8.824657534 6   N
8.063013699 3   Y
8.016438356 4   Y
8.054794521 3   N
8.095890411 3   Y
8.095890411 3   N
8.076712329 6   N
8.060273973 3   Y
8.347945205 2   Y
8.035616438 4   Y
8.093150685 4   Y
```

Comment: The state-of-the-art way of handling this in economics is to just use robust standard errors; the estimate might not be efficient, but a weighted least squares estimate is only efficient if you've correctly specified the form of the variance covariacne matrix, and who can say they've done that?